# write json to a file using jQuery and Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to write a json file based upon a filled in Form

So I used an external Library for jquery that converts the Form into legitimate JSON.
When I console.log that output I do get a valid json data returned.

So whenever I pass the data into a php using $.ajax and write the content to a file
the PHP saves the file but the inside it just says "NULL"

here is my AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var json = $("#user-form").serializeJSON();
    $.ajax({
        url: "writejson.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: json,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
})
```

And here is my PHP:

```
<?php
    $myFile = "kiosk.json";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh,var_export($_POST['data'], true));
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

and here is what the outputted file says:

```
NULL
```

I tried looking it up here first and tried numerous options but none of them seem to save the correct data.
really strange.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$_POST['data']` is `null`, as expected. You aren't sending post data, you're sending a string as the request body.

Comment: This was true, this and the post below I had to stringify the json first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always change your json string from this

```
 var json = $("#user-form").serializeJSON();
```

to this

```
 var json = {data: $("#user-form").serializeJSON()};
```

That way when you try to retrieve $_POST['data'], it will actually be set because you defined it.

**EDIT: Important point by Shuyinsama - pointed out that you have to use the `JSON.stringify` method on JSON objects before posting them to PHP:**

> In my case this is what I did:
>
> ```
> var jsontext = JSON.stringify($("#user-form").serializeJSON());
>
> var json = {data: jsontext};
> ```
>
> and then use the first PHP file to write it into a valid JSON file.

And always remember you can use the `json_decode();` within PHP if you ever need to do some processing on your JSON data, and `json_encode();`, respectively.

Comment: Same problem the output is just
  
     NULL

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a post variable called "data", this will return null.  You might want to try [`http_get_request_body()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php)